# Share Link in Email won't redirect after "submit"

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook, socialpost, social-content

I've coded a Social Forward into my email template, and everything seems to be working until we click "Post to Facebook".  The post ends up on my wall, but the browser doesn't reload - it freezes on a page with the following URL:

[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_)

Here's the HTML used in the Social Forward:

```
<a href="%%=GetSocialPublishURLByName('Facebook','US','FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook')=%%">

RegionStart[ socialslot:"FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook",
                   title:"FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook",
                   description:"Here's a Great FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook"]
```

SOME HTML CODE IN THE EMAIL

```
RegionEnd[ socialslot:"FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook",
                  title:"FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook",
                  description:"Here's a Great FREE Offer I'm trying to Share on Facebook"]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank You!

Comment: Anyone, anyone?  Bueller? Bueller?  Would love to know if anyone has any feedback.  I'm wondering if this is a Marketing Cloud issue?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with SFDC Marketing Cloud support, and they confirmed that the issue is not with the SOCIAL FORWARD mechanism, but with Facebook's code.  As mentioned above, the code is successfully creating the post, but the redirect is not working.

The suggestion is to ask for a product improvement in SFDC MC to find an alternative way of posting facebook messages from email.